# onafterprint stops working when inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing

The following `onafterprint` callback gets executed just fine on a simple regular page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onafterprint = function(e) {
    console.log(['label onafterprint', e]);
}
</script>
```

When I put that page into an `iframe`, and manually run `iframe.contentWindow.print()` from within the parent page, the print dialogue shows up correctly, but it doesn't fire the `onafterprint` anymore. However, when I print the whole actual parent page (that includes the iframe in question, and a few more), the iframe's onafterprint does indeed fire for every iframe ([and it's the expected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756283/why-an-iframe-after-print-event-listener-is-fired-after-i-print-in-the-main-wind/57756544#57756544)), so the callback must be configured and attached correctly.

But how do I make the iframe fire it's own `onafterprint` when I print just that iframe? I have several iframes on a page showing document previews, and I need this callback to fire on each of them individually.

What have I researched:

- [`matchMedia`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41012827/detect-print-events-from-iframe/41016001#41016001) seems overcomplicated and is not cross-browser compatible
- this is not an issue of [calling `.print()` too soon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756283/why-an-iframe-after-print-event-listener-is-fired-after-i-print-in-the-main-wind/57756544#57756544) because in my case it's being called on a button click

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it is still somehow one of those 'too soon' situations, but unlike `.print()` in the linked answer, in my case the iframe itself was loading too soon. It works fine as soon as I load the iframes manually. Still investigating